# Is there a way to change the world map, into some custom made maps, in kibana

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch, gis, kibana, qgis

i was making an angular front end for a real-time for an application --

( a mock global open market simulation sotware, in a fictitious world with fake countries with fake maps.-it will generate large amount( not huge though) of data in near real time, it will do complex market economy  analysis, predictions and such.. ).

I  found out about kibana, literally 40 minutes before i'm writing this, (So i've no idea).

I see that, kibana uses something like, geo_points and geo hashes on top of the real world map. If, i could make a custom designed world map, for my needs, in QGIS,by georeferencing some png images ,also store them as tile maps in my server as POSTGIS datasets.

**How to load a custom base map in kibana from my server.?**

***what base map is used with kibana anyway.?***

Comment: Maybe you need GeoServer to load custom base maps.